# How to skip owin authorization for certain paths

Tags: c#, owin, swashbuckle

I have a ASP.NET Web Api 2 project where I'm using multiple authentication mechanisms(Windows Auth & API KEY Auth).

My Startup Class Looks something like this

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            ConfigureWinAuth(app);
            ConfigureApiKeyAuth(app);    

            app.Use<AuthMiddleware>();
            app.Use<LicenseMiddleware>();

            WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);           
            app.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);    

        }

        public void ConfigureWinAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/win-auth-token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new WindowsAuthorizationServerProvider()
            };

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }

        public void ConfigureApiKeyAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseApiKeyAuthentication(new ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Provider = new ApiKeyAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = ValidateIdentity,
                    OnGenerateClaims = GenerateClaims
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Now I also need to add support for Swagger docs I'm using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) for this purpose.

Now if I browser server/swagger in the browser I'm getting 401 which is expected since Owin requests Authorization Header to be present on all the request. Now I need to tell Owin dont expect this header when the path is **/swagger**.

I wont be able to use [AllowAnonymous] attribute since the way swashbuckle works is it dynamically creates a url to serve the docs. the default is http://localhost/swagger

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this?

**Update 1**

I have commented out all the Authentication and Middlewares and still getting the 401

```
//ConfigureWinAuth(app);
            //ConfigureApiKeyAuth(app);


            //app.Use<AuthMiddleware>();
            //app.Use<LicenseMiddleware>();
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is the swagger folder created inside the "wwwroot" subfolder of your project or not?

Comment: No Swashbuckle does not create any static files or folders, it dynamically adds a web api route called /swagger, and returns the  swagger ui dynamically using reflection to find out controllers and action method and their signatures

Comment: There is no call to `SwaggerConfig.Register()` in your startup code?

Comment: I have a class called SwaggerConfig which is decorated with below attribute which initializes the swagger

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Kovai.AtomicScope.Api.SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

Comment: What is the content of your SwaggerConfig class? Can you provide a [mcve] to show your issue because out of the box in a new web api project using authorization and Swashbuckle, swagger is accessible without being authorized.

Comment: Also, provide the implementation of `AuthMiddleware` which seems to be your own implementation and possibly `LicenseMiddleware`. Problem is most likely in the implementation of those two classes.

Comment: The request does not hit any of those middlewares, its throwing 401 before it comes to the middleware